Returning a list of values in column based on an association table
Schema:
Users
- id
- name

Users_In_Company
-company_id
-user_id

Companies
-id
-name

I have to return a list of users, and 1 column should have a list of all the companies they are associated too.
SELECT u.*
FROM users u

Output:
ID   NAME   Companies
1    John   Acme1, Amazon, Walmart

Is a lateral join what can be used here?
Note:
This is for a search results query, so I need to keep performance in mind.  I may return up to 1000 rows per request.

This question is similar to: Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@IłyaBursov  My data is coming from a join table, it isn't in the main table as per my question details.   I have to join to get the value, and I don't want to group by or is that fine performance wise?

We can present several query examples that output the expected result. With LATERAL or other JOIN. However, it is impossible to talk about their performance unless you provide additional data on table sizes and indexes. More importantly, how and what you are searching for.

Yes, you can use a LATERAL join to achieve the result.
To get it we need to aggregate the list of company names for each user and then return it as part of result.
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.name, 
    COALESCE(c.companies, '') AS companies
FROM 
    users u
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        string_agg(c.name, ', ') AS companies
    FROM 
        users_in_company uic
    JOIN 
        companies c ON uic.company_id = c.id
    WHERE 
        uic.user_id = u.id
) c on 1=1;

alternatively you can achieve the same with left join and string_agg
SELECT u.id, 
       u.name, 
       STRING_AGG(c.name, ', ') AS companies
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_in_company uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
LEFT JOIN companies c ON uc.company_id = c.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY u.id;

Refer to this link: dbfiddle
